# Rails Application elem is null in classie.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails

In my Rails application my collapse navebar is not changing it style while scrolling and also an error occur in inspect element console which is:

```
TypeError: elem is null
      elem.classList.add( c );
```

Classie .js in which error occurs:

```
( function( window ) {

'use strict';

// class helper functions from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo

function classReg( className ) {
  return new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + className + "(\\s+|$)");
}

// classList support for class management
// altho to be fair, the api sucks because it won't accept multiple classes at once
var hasClass, addClass, removeClass;

if ( 'classList' in document.documentElement ) {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return elem.classList.contains( c );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.add( c );
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.remove( c );
  };
}
else {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return classReg( c ).test( elem.className );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    if ( !hasClass( elem, c ) ) {
      elem.className = elem.className + ' ' + c;
    }
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.className = elem.className.replace( classReg( c ), ' ' );
  };
}

function toggleClass( elem, c ) {
  var fn = hasClass( elem, c ) ? removeClass : addClass;
  fn( elem, c );
}

var classie = {
  // full names
  hasClass: hasClass,
  addClass: addClass,
  removeClass: removeClass,
  toggleClass: toggleClass,
  // short names
  has: hasClass,
  add: addClass,
  remove: removeClass,
  toggle: toggleClass
};
```

i change the sequence of require library but it not helping.

```
//= require jquery 
//= require jquery-1.11.0.js 
//= require classie.js 
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap.js
//= require bootstrap.min.js
//= require agency.js
//= require contact_me.js
//= require cbpAnimatedHeader.js
//= require cbpAnimatedHeader.min.js
//= require jqBootstrapValidation.js
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had to also integrate the Agency theme and also am getting that error. For some reason the header variable on the cbpAnimatedHeader.js file using document.querySelector always results to null. So I converted the entire script to Jquery:

```
$(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 300){
            $('.navbar-default').addClass('navbar-shrink');
        }
        else{
            $('.navbar-default').removeClass('navbar-shrink');
        }
    });
});
```

This might not directly answer your question but it does solve the problem for now.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue when I used the minified JS, so using just the normal JS(removing the minified one) solved the issue for me.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

after doing this :

```html
$(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 300){
            $('.navbar-default').addClass('navbar-shrink');
        }
        else{
            $('.navbar-default').removeClass('navbar-shrink');
        }
    });
});
```

enqueue script()

```html
 http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js
```

in function.php.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a theme which you have purchased from wrapbootstrap.com or other theme and content provider sites out there, then you have to take extra care of how the theme loads and uses its js plugins.

Most themes use a multitude of javascript plugins and in almost all cases you'll find a single javascript file which loads and initializes all these plugins.

I advise you to revise the main js file initializing and driving your theme.

In my theme - vitality which I have purchased from wrapbootstrap - the vitality.js file was the main javascript file and I notices that it didn't use $(document).ready() function to initialize all other javascript. To my knowledge Rails expects a document.ready function, so all I did is replace (function($) { with $(document).ready(function() { at the beginning of the file, and voila everything just works like a charm. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Open
"views > layouts > application.html.erb"
 Now move this code `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>` 
to be after `<%= yield %>` and before `</body>`
It guarantees that DOM elements are loaded on the page before JavaScript runs.